# Why isnt the essential storage package mentioned in the Spring tutorial

Tags: spring

I tried to follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ which is about uploading files in Spring, but I wasn't able to complete it. Because something was missing.

After downloading the inital project there is a storage package which isn't mentioned in the tutorial it self, it conatins essential classes in order to make the tutorial project work.
[The Package Im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA5iB.png)

So where does the package come from and why isn't in mentioned?

Comment: Welcome on StackOveflow. I suggest you to read [ask], and then [edit] your post to better explain your issue. You can also take a look to different version if it simply have been added after the tutorial does, or just ignore this if you don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the missing information you are talking about is covered in the project documentation itself.

In the [README](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files) there is a [Create a File Upload Controller sections](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files#create-a-file-upload-controller) where they mention:

> You will need to provide a StorageService so that the controller can
> interact with a storage layer (such as a file system). The following
> listing (from
> **src/main/java/com/example/uploadingfiles/storage/StorageService.java**)
> shows that interface...

Maybe this explains the lack of information you've detected.

**UPDATE:**

After double checking the [tutorial page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), it also mentions it at the end of the section 'Create a File Upload Controller'.

Comment: The mention the Service but not any of the exceptions which are already in the initial project. Am i missing a step?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Can you elaborate a bit more the exceptions you're talking about?